# force an R(Studio) dialog window front

Tags: r, dialog, window, rstudio

A (I'm hoping) fairly short and simple question:  I'm wondering if there is a way anyone knows of (via R code) to force an R(Studio) dialog window to the front (of any then-open windows)?

A bit more specific context:  I added a .Last function to my Rprofile.site file to check for updates to R whenever I close R (which I usually use with RStudio).  Here is the .Last function:

```
.Last <- function() {
     updateR()
   }
```

When I use R (not RStudio), the update-check dialog pops to the front on close.  However, when I'm using RStudio, the update-check window pops up behind the RStudio window, which is rather annoying and non-intuitive.  I'd really like to know if there is a way to add some code to the .Last function to make any on-close update dialog windows pop to the front.

Any thoughts will be much appreciated!

=)  Brian